# Editing plist file(objective c)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, plist

I'm new to Objective C, and currently working on an iphone app. My app needs to take user inputs(strings) and store them, so I am using plist to store the data. Currently, I can read from the plist file. However, when I tried to write to the plist file, the file itself does not change at all.

What I'm trying to do is to append user's input to the existing plist file. So I read the plist file and store the array to a mutableArray. Then, I use the addObject function to append the new user input at the end of the mutableArray. Till this point, everything is working fine, and the mutableArray is exactly how I wanted it. The last step is what's not working for me:

`[mutableArray writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];`

I assume that the my plist file(located in my resource folder along with the .h and .m files) should be changed after this line is executed and the new user input should be appended, but the file doesn't seem to change at all.

I have read some people say that I should copy the plist file from NSBundle to the Documents directory because the plist file is in the resource folder, but among almost all the tutorials on youtube, there has not been a problem like that and their code still work fine with their plist file in the resource folder.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: That **is** the problem. You cannot write into the bundle of an iOS application

Comment: If the plist is in the application bundle, it is not writable on a real device.  A quick test would be to run your code on the simulator.  If protection is the problem, I believe it will work on the simulator and fail on the phone.

Comment: Thank you vadian and Phillip! Just another question: So should I copy the plist file from the bundle to the document directory only on the first launch of the application and access it from there? Or is there another way to do it? I guess there isn't a reason to include a plist file in the resource folder from the start since I can just create a new plist file in the document directory when the app launches and go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you must copy file from NSBundle to NSDocumentUser for example file "NimrokhRavanshenasi.sqlite3"

```
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *writableDbtPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NimrokhRavanshenasi.sqlite3"];

BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDbtPath];
NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NimrokhRavanshenasi.sqlite3"];
NSError *error;
success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDbtPath error:&error];


NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
if([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:writableDbtPath]){
    if (sqlite3_open([writableDbtPath UTF8String], &_contactDB) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to open database!");
```

Comment: Thank you afshin and Ekta! I'm just curious if the plist file is needed in the resource folder, since I can just create a new plist file in the document directory when the app launches, instead of copying the plist file from the resource folder.

Comment: File.sqlite3 the example you can use this code for file.plist and continue

Comment: First Create a Plist file on NSBunlde and use this Code for copy file from NSBundle to NSDocumentUser